# Convert Binary QString to QPixmap

Tags: qt, data-conversion, qstring, qpixmap, qtcpsocket

I'm receiving a binary thru FTP and storing it as a `QString`. The original image was BMP but to pass through FTP I converted it to `QPixmap`. I'm able to successfully receive this binary but I can't convert back to a `QPixmap` or some sort of format to display that image.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe `QImage::fromData()` will help?

Comment: Where is comming QPixmap? From QTcpServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Convert QString to  QByteArray data with *QString::toLatin1(), QString::toLocal8Bit()*. Think work only one of methods

2) Read QByteArray with

```
bool QPixmap::loadFromData(const QByteArray & data, ...
```

Possibly functions in point one will encode data to another(text) encoding. Then try to convert QChar* from QString::data to QByteArray. Or write that QChar's into file and read QPixmap from file.

Comment: Yup, thats absolutelly perfect! thnk you so much bro!!